# Using two useeffect react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to use react with hooks. I have this state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
    titel: "",
    somethingElse: "",
    tabledata: [],
});
```

I have two useeffect:

```
// componentDidMount, Initial variable deklaration
useEffect(() => {
    //Do something

    //Set initial states
    setState({
        ...state,
        titel: props.titel,
        somethingElse: props.somethingElse,
    })

}, []);

// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
useEffect(() => {

    //Do something and generate tabledata
    let tabledata ....

    //Set tabledata
    setState({
        ...state,
        tabledata: tabledata,
    })

}, [props.taenzer]);
```

Now I have the behavior, that the second useeffect is overwriting the first useeffect setState command.
My variable titel and somethingElse is always empty.

Now I could change my deklaration of state, something in this way:

```
const [titel, setTitel] = useState<>({
    titel = ""
});
const [somethingElse, setSomethingElse] = useState<>({
    somethingElse = ""
});
```

But this makes the whole unclear and it is not so easy to set the state of several variables in one time like we could with setState(...state, titel="Hello", somethingElse="Else")

Any other possibility?

Comment: What do you mean by "second useeffect is overwriting the first useeffect setState command"? I can't see it from example.

Comment: Tbh, i like the second approach. Since hooks i try to skip nested states as much as possible. With this approach you can manipulate state really easy in a immutable way. If i go nested, i go for `useReducer`

Comment: Looks like a race condition. During mount you will get two effects executing and the order is probably undetermined so you will get two nearly simultaneous `setState` and the last one will "stick" but most likely both will be reading the same initial state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the second useeffect is overwriting the first useeffect setState

`useState` function doesn't automatically merge the state. So you would need to make use of the previous state accessible via callback.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const tabledata = ...
    setState(prevState => ({ // use previous state
      ...prevState,
      tabledata
    }))
  }, [props.taenzer]
)
```

> Any other possibility?

You can have [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) of your state via `props` and remove the first effect (without dependency)

```
const [{ title, somethingElse, tabledata }, setState] = useState<State>({
    ...props,
    tabledata: [],
});
```